# What to do while booted into a machine with a broken /home

Tags: disk, dmesg

I was just running some DL code in a jupyter notebook and watching a youtube video in another tab. I heard the GPU fan turn off, but I saw an error about an IO issue. I did some poking around. When I try to touch a file in my `/home`, I get:

```
cat: .bash_profile: Input/output error
```

I checked dmesg and it doesn't look good.

```
[ 6187.973458] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc5): dx_probe:744: inode #10485761: lblock 0: comm gnome-shell: error -5 reading directory block
[ 6188.018594] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 5
[ 6188.018620] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 5
[ 6189.798280] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc5): dx_probe:744: inode #10485761: lblock 0: comm dmesg: error -5 reading directory block
```

I'm pretty sure that this means that my drive is finished.

What can I save from my RAM etc., so that I won't have to recreate everything when I set up a new drive? Anything that I can save from my `/home` to another partition would make me happy. I haven't rebooted yet.

Comment: If it were me, I'd have just shutdown & assessed from a 'live' environment (starting with `smartctl` etc).  Either way, I'd have killed the GUI (which writes work files to $HOME), and limit myself to text tty/terminals, and `scp` to save anything you need elsewhere. Personally I'd go the way of re-create (or using backups) instead of risking copying incomplete/suspect files to a new environment, so I'd only grab what you absolutely need.

Comment: Update on this... I ran a disk check and repair and was able to recover the partition. So anyone coming to this from bing or yandex or whatever, try that.

Comment: It's great that you were able to recover, but it would be wise to [check the SMART status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) of the drive in question and [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) regularly.